# Django <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'> . Как правильно читать?

Tags: django-orm

Всем привет!

Пытаюсь разобраться с Django.
Вопрос 1. Из модели пытаюсь взять содержимое и посмотреть что возвращает запрос. Какой тип данных.

```
>>> from posts.models import Post, User

>>> latest = Post.objects.all()

>>> print(type(latest))
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
```

Получаю `<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>`. Как это правильно прочитать? Объект типа `QuerySet` класса `query` класса `models` встроенного класса `django.db` ?  Не понимаю.
Смотрел документацию, но не до конца понимаю (или вообще не понимаю).

Вопрос 2. Объект типа `QuerySet` это список содержимого запроса к БД? Это итерируемый объект, к содержимому которого можно обратиться через точечную нотацию. Получается, что объект типа `QuerySet` содержит в себе список словарей?

Comment: Циклом пройтись.

Comment: Этот итератор при проходе циклом выдаёт экземпляры класса Post. Никаких словарей там не будет, пока вы явно их не запросите их методом [.values()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values)

Comment: Ок, спасибо. По второму вопросу понял. А что на счет первого? @andreymal

Comment: А что непонятно? django.db.models.query - это модуль, QuerySet - это класс, который создан в этом модуле.

Comment: Спасибо! @andreymal